# Mysql8 fail to upsert generated uuid

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, upsert, uuid

I have a mysql8 table with 2 columns: `ID`(Int) AND `UUID`(Varchar36):

```
CREATE TABLE `upsert_test` (
  `ID` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'id;',
  `UUID` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I need to mimic the `upsert` behavior without unique-index, and finally I got the following sql command, which works fine with mysql 5.7:

```
INSERT INTO upsert_test
SELECT 1 AS ID, UUID() AS "UUID"
FROM upsert_test
WHERE ID=1
HAVING COUNT(*)=0;
```

However when upgraded to mysql8.0, only a null UUID is inserted, as flowing:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM upsert_test;
+------+------+
| ID   | UUID |
+------+------+
|    1 | NULL |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And if I execute the `select` sub-command, I do get a valid UUID (this query is actually executed before inserting any data):

```
mysql> SELECT 1 AS ID, UUID() AS "UUID"
    -> FROM upsert_test
    -> WHERE ID=1
    -> HAVING COUNT(*)=0;
+----+--------------------------------------+
| ID | UUID                                 |
+----+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | a1fbea94-f6c4-11eb-903c-0242ac110002 |
+----+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And it just can't be inserted.
And if I ignore the `HAVING` part:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO upsert_test
    -> SELECT 2 AS ID, UUID() AS "UUID";
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM upsert_test;
+------+--------------------------------------+
| ID   | UUID                                 |
+------+--------------------------------------+
|    1 | NULL                                 |
|    2 | 033e03f7-f6c5-11eb-903c-0242ac110002 |
+------+--------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

We can see that a valid UUID is inserted.

I've been struggling with this issue for this whole afternoon, just can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: What indexes are on the table? !  You _must_ have two.

Comment: There's no index. Why do I "must" have two?

Comment: So that it knows which row(s) to upsert!

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a subselect to have a valid row with both values

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `upsert_test` (
>   `ID` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'id;',
>   `UUID` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL
> )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO upsert_test
> SELECT *  FROM
> (SELECT 1 AS ID, UUID() AS "UUID"
> FROM upsert_test
> WHERE ID=1
> HAVING COUNT(*)=0) t1;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM upsert_test
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | UUID                                
> -: | :-----------------------------------
>  1 | 63b0fa5b-f6d1-11eb-871d-00163e64f9cc
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c4395eb31ca8b45233c5e9e0a85e2f48)*

Comment: Thank you @nbk, that solves the problem. So, what actually is the problem that causes the issue?

Comment: uuid is not executed as the query is run, but when mysql has to run the subselect first it runs completely including the uuid() probably a bug